# White page betwen routes in react routing animation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to create animation in react-routing and have a problem: animation works, **but** there is a blank (white) page between transitions. It seems like a white blink. Blink goes first, and after that, the animation is. What is the problem?

**index.js** - main component which imports App component as below.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter >
      <Route render={({ location }) => (
          <App location={location}/>
      )}/>

    </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

then **app.js** which has routing.

```
function App({location}) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <main>
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
              timeout={200}
              classNames='page'
              key={location.pathname}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Main}/>
              <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
              <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
            </Switch>
           </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      </main>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

then **style.css**

```
.page {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}

.page-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.page-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 200ms, transform 300ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is no different than other usage of `CSSTransition`, just make
> sure to pass `location` to `Switch` so it can match the old location
> as it animates out.

```
<Switch location={location}>
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions

Comment: I have components, when one is unmounted and another has not mounted yet -my page is white, how to make animation ignore white blank page and see only components and animate transition between them?